# Magnolia image variation set the crop position

Tags: magnolia

In Magnolia, I believe that with image variations if you set crop to true the crop position is center by default. Eg. crops the top and the bottom equally. However, I would like to create a version that only crops from the top or from the bottom (or from left / right). This is very easy to do in Wordpress, but I can't find any documentation for Magnolia.

relevant links

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/How+to+work+with+images+using+imgfn
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS53/Imaging+module

Found this on google groups

https://groups.google.com/a/magnolia-cms.com/forum/#!searchin/dev-list/crop%7Csort:date/dev-list/duMR1ePQHEk/lJK4_d-1AwAJ

> Hey guys,
>
> Currently the magnolia imaging module cropping and resizing is working
>   very nicely for us.  I'm implementing responsive images, but would
>   like responsive header images as well (which means I want to set a
>   focal point on the images) --> for example; focus on top right and
>   then crop image accordingly.
>
> What JAVA class would I have to change to edit the standard behaviour
>   of the cropping focussing on the center of the image?
>
> I already looked into this java operation: 
>   [url]https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/modules/magnolia-imaging/3.1.4/apidocs/info/magnolia/imaging/operations/cropresize/AutoCropAndResize.html#getEffectiveTargetSize(java.awt.image.BufferedImage,
>   info.magnolia.imaging.operations.cropresize.Coords,
>   info.magnolia.imaging.ParameterProvider)[/url]

Comment: any ideas for this? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this while looking for topics regarding the Focal Point extension for Magnolia which is supposed to do exactly what you are planning to implement yourself.

Maybe this will help you: https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/EX/Focal+Points#FocalPoints-Installation

Apart from that, the default class that does the Resizing is

```
info.magnolia.templating.imaging.variation.SimpleResizeVariation
```

This is mentioned briefly in the Magnolia documentation

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DEV/Scaled+image+quality?focusedCommentId=82122990#comment-82122990